# Sending SMS gives CMS error 304

Tags: c#, gsm, at-command

I'm working on a program in C# that can send a SMS from my computer using my GSM modem, and I got most of my program to work.

I can send most Hayes AT commands like: "AT" and "AT+CGMI;+CGMM", which returns the message "OK", so I know I can communicate with the modem.

However I DO have problems sending a standard 7-bit encoded message from the modem to my cell phone.

With the help of PDUspy I have a somewhat confident that I'm encoding my message right.

However the following code fails miserably:

```
public string SendEncodedSms(string reciever, string message)
{
  string response = GetResponse("AT+CMGF=0");
  if (isFine(response))
  {
    string encodedBody = "000100" + EncodedReceiver(reciever) + "0000";
    encodedBody += EncodeToSeptet(message);

    int cmgs_header = encodedBody.Length / 2;

    port.WriteLine("AT+CMGS=" + cmgs_header.ToString() + "\r\n");
    port.WriteLine(encodedBody + (char)26);

    return ReadResponse(300);
  }
  else throw new ApplicationException("Cant go into SMS PDU mode");
}
```

There five function calls inside:

- GetResponse() is function that works as a wrapper when communicating with the modem - always making sure each command ends with a "\r", and returns OK or Error depending on the response from the modem.
- isFine() is a simple function that check whether or not the response from GetResponse() contained a "OK" message.
- ReadResponse() returns any response from the modem whether that is OK or any error messages and whatever there also might be embedded between the AT command and the status message.
- EncodeReceiver() encode the receivers phone number in reverse nibble notation. E.g. 12345678 becomes 21436587.
- EncodeToSeptet() Encodes the message from 8bit notation to 7bit notation.

All functions have been confirmed to work fine using PDU spy and responses sent to debug window.

Calling `SendEncodedSms("<my phone number>", "test")` returns:

```
AT+CMGS=17

0001000A91xxxxxxxxxx000004F4F29C0E

+CMS ERROR: 304
```

I replaced my encoded phone number for privacy issues... ;-)

- Is there anybody who can give me a hint what I am failing at?

UPDATED:

Link hinted I was calculating cmgs_header wrong.

After a bit of cleaning code I got:

```
public string SendEncodedSms(string receiver, string message)
{
  if(isFine("AT+CMGF=0"))
  {
     string encodedBody = EncodedReceiver(receiver) + "0000";
     encodedBody += EncodeToSeptet(message);

     /* The +2 in calculation is a hack. Its probleby two of the octets 
      * in 000100 that should be a part of length calculation. But need 
      * to verify in against severeal sites.
      */
     int cmgs_header = (encodedBody.Length / 2) + 2;

     encodedBody = "000100" + encodedBody;

     // Rest is as before.

    ...

  }

  else ...
}
```

Comment: I should mention "port" is an instance of SerialPort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe [this](http://www.esato.com/archive/t.php/t-74665) helps you. Why don't you send the SMS in text mode?

Comment: Unfortuantely I can't use Text mode due to I need to receive SMS containing scandinavian letters.

The letters are supported by the GSM 7bit alphabet, but apparently not by text mode. Hence I need to code/decode PDUs instead.

Working on the decode PDU part atm, så I might as well use it to verify my ENCODE part is imoplemented correct! ;-)

I can receive SMS messages, so decoding should be easyer to debug.

Comment: Hmm... Link looks interesting... Gotta check it out - when I get back from work. :-)

Comment: Yep - the hint was there - apparently my calculation of cmgs_header was off, it was 8 hex too long, which PDUspy didn't catch.

The hint was that is hould not include the trailing '000100' in the calculation of cmgs_header.

Answer (score 0):

Try substitute code line with this,

```
port.WriteLine("AT+CMGS=" + cmgs_header.ToString() + "\r");
```

Some modems expect strictly CR after length. LF is parsed already as data, 
see example below:

```
AT+CMGS=14 CR
0001030691214365000004C9E9340B
```

Comment: Heh! About one year since my last revisit to this question! Yes I found that the "\r" can be a royal pain. When I worked on communicating with a modem, it was against a Huawei USB stick. 

My error came down to a calculate header length wrong.